# Variable in bpy. context

Tags: python

Is it possible to insert a variable into a bpy context?

Like

```
bpy.types.Scene.propertyNameProp = StringProperty(name="Name", default="", maxlen=10, description="Name of your property")
propName = bpy.context.scene.propertyNameProp
bpy.types.Scene.propName()
```

Comment: Yes you can, but I think that you are heading into what Drivers are created for.
Specifically registering your code within the Driver_Namespace. [Click here for a similar solution](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48127/possible-to-use-object-speed-acceleration-as-driver-variable/48137#48137)