# How to get one object to copy a character's location but 10 frames later in bge

Tags: game-engine, parent

I'm making a 2D platformer game and the character I have is similar to that of donkey kong country. When the character you are playing moves (such as donkey kong), the unplayable character (like diddy kong) follows and does exactly the same thing except a few frames later and ends up by his side again. I am going to learn python, but have not yet since I am doing school, and I have not found a way (python or no python) to get this to work. I have tried doing a slow parent, but that cuts corners and the character that is following ends up floating or dipping below ground level. Here is a quick depiction of my problem:

[image: following object cuts corners when slow parent is used]

I would love it if someone has a solution, but if it involves python, you'll have to show me step by step how to do it. :)
Thanks!

Comment: Related : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/108484/29586

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for! I tried to follow the directions, but they still seem geared toward people who know what they're doing more or less. I don't even know what a driver function is or how to set it up. I have the python copied and registered. Would you mind showing me the rest or point me to tutorials of how to do it? :)

Comment: This was my best effort. :) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1alJHVgy_2WTMMkP5aw5PT57HH3iJs2-T/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @DaDudell Looking at your screenshot you've just about there. All that should be required is for you to change the Expr in the Drivers section (just under where it says 'Scripted Expression' to something like `drv_delay(frame,"sphere_x", 10, var)`. I'll try and put together an answer to try and clarify for your situation.

Comment: That would be fantastic because I did that last thing and something is still not right. I must have messed it up somewhere in there. :)

Comment: Aha. I got it to work, but only when I have an action for it. Would it work for when I'm using motion controls in the game engine?

Comment: @DaDudell That’s great. I’m afraid I don’t use the game engine very much so I don’t really know - although I don’t see why it wouldn’t work as it’s just a driver after all. It would be great if you could write an answer with your solution so that youcan then mark it as ‘accepted’ (you’ll gain reputation for this and the answer will be there to help other users in the future if they search for this).

Comment: That's totally fine! I'll ask this on blenderartists too and I'll post the answer if I can figure one out. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Hey we figured it out on blenderartists.org! It works great. :) [How to get one object to copy a character’s location but 10 frames later](https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-get-one-object-to-copy-a-characters-location-but-10-frames-later/1126113)