# Animate A Change In Speed (Velocity Keyframes)

Tags: animation, add-on

In blender you can keyframe a parameter's value, but is possible to keyframe **rate of change** in that value (the speed). For example, animating a rotating wheel smoothly speeding up, staying at a constant speed, and then smoothly slowing down by keyframing 0 rpm then keyframing let's say 150 rpm, etc.

Seems like a basic thing. Can blender do this or are there any add-ons that do this?

**Edit:**

(I changed the question above to clarify)

I know how to do animations and change how it transition between keyframes. My question is about changing not the value itself, but the rate of change of that value. You could obviously do the example above by hand, but it would be a tedious and if you wanted to extend the time the wheel rotated for during the constant speed portion you would also need to change all the values after that. Additional note, I know there some add-ons to simplify animating a car, but I just need something just for rate of change.

Comment: Ohhh okay, that clarification really changed the context of the question. Perhaps "Velocity Keyframes" would be a better descriptor for what you want. I don't think that feature exists yet in Blender (I do agree that it would be really helpful though). Consider adding that to the "Right-Click Select" group in the Blender Community website. Perhaps the devs can start working on that as an add-on for a later date.

Comment: See the btrace addon.

Comment: See [How to add driver expression result from previous frame to current frames expression (way to compound expression output?)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/249866/60486), as well as [adding a delay for a driver](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/108373/60486)

Comment: You could use some math with simulation nodes for that

Answer (score 0):

You can also quickly access presets for the graph editor by pressing **T** on the keyboard. This will give you option like *bounce*, *smooth slowing*, and more!