# Creating a driver that references a value at a given frame

Tags: python, scripting, drivers

Is there a way to create a driver, that reads a value at an arbitrary time?

Example: An object that follows an other object with a delay.

Comment: you can ask for a frame in the driver....if frame == 134 ....

Comment: Ok, but the queston is how can I access a value of an animation curve at a given time, not the current frame number.

Comment: See _`Text Editor > Templates > Python > Driver Functions`_

Comment: For a delay rather than from a specific frame, try https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/108484/29586