# Make an object turn / rotate with its front face to the next location in an animation

Tags: python, animation, scripting

I created a cube location animation, where the only keyframes set are from location A to location B to location C.

**My goal:** When I click play so the "front face" or in my case the arrow on top of the cube, always points to the next location destination it's going be. Think of it like a driving car, always forward.

**My request:** *I don't want* to create rotation keyframes *manually* nor set specific rotation at each location keyframe manually.
The reason for this is to be generic and apply for other location animations.

Solutions using scripts are also welcome.

[image: Illustration]

Thank you.

Comment: I think I've found something that might work for you. Instead of using keyframes or trying to use constraints to make the arrow always point towards the next location (which would require keyframes either on the constraint itself or for moving the goal) you can use this solution that runs on scripts and with animation nodes. It automatically points objects in the direction that they are travelling, which should work for your purposes. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/240066/61453

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to create rotation keyframes manually nor set specific rotation at each location keyframe manually.

No problem.

Animate your cube's location as desired.  Set extrapolation mode in graph editor (shift e for me) to linear.  Duplicate the cube.  Disable rendering on that duplicate.  On graph editor, move all keyframes -1 in time (g x -1 enter.)

Give your original cube a damped track constraint targeting your duplicate.  Set the track axis to be whatever is the "front" axis of that cube (the direction your arrow is pointing.)