# Shading according to velocity

Tags: physics, shaders

I have a rigid body simulation of many objects and would like to change how they're shaded depending on velocity. It's easy to get location from object info node, but how about change in location between current/previous frame?

Comment: It's actually not something you can do easily in Blender as far as I know. This require a little bit of scripting knowledge, read this post to get started: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48127/possible-to-use-object-speed-acceleration-as-driver-variable

Comment: Would a "baking" solution suffice?  _ie_ once the rigid body simulation is baked, can evaluate a  keyframe , or a custom property value for velocity and acceleration from the global location of objects  at each frame of sim.

Comment: Baking a solution would be fine. That said the velocity of objects can change from frame to frame though.